# E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time and have no experience with linux.

```
buntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks
```

I am trying to set up a bootable usb and I can't figure out why **E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks** keeps happening.

Comment: Welcome, there doesn't seem to be any relation between installing the package and creating a bootable usb.

Answer (score 4):

`gnome-tweaks` is in the *universe* repository.

Package: gnome-tweaks (3.28.1-1) [universe]  (from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-tweaks)

Open **Software and Updates** on your computer and tick the box beside "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)"

Then click "close" and enter your password if prompted

Comment: @maxbear123 I never use the 'software app' whatever that might be. I install using `apt`.

Comment: @maxbear123, nope `apt update` will do just fine.

Comment: @maxbear I have 6 ubuntu pcs that I keep regularly updated and I have never, not once, "opened the software app". I don't know what you are trying to say, but you can create a desktop system, set it up, and keep it updated, and never, ever use the "software app". The "software app" AFAIK is just a GUI frontend for `apt`.

Comment: @maxbear123 I'm not trying to answer any question. I'm just saying your first comment is wrong. Users don't  ever *have* to use the "software app".

Comment: My servers don't even have a desktop, so they certainly don't have the "software app"

Comment: You just have to use apt-get update first.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my first comment.